# Laravel display object from foreach

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

i want to echo ouptut from controller
When i dump this object i get all data like i want, but how to echo that
[I want to display this data like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffeCM.png)

Here is my controller

```
$pkm = DB::table('magacin_pkms')->select(
    'magacin_pkms.status',
    'magacin_pkms.izdao_to',
    'users.name as izdaoFirstName',
    'users.lastname as izdaoLastName',
    'magacin_pkms.vrednost',
    'magacin_pkms.izdao_by',
    'magacin_pkms.izdao_at'
)
    ->join('users', 'id_user', 'izdao_to')
    ->where('magacin_pkms.status', 2)
    ->orderBy('izdao_to')
    ->get();

$driverIDs = array_unique($pkm->pluck('izdao_to')->toArray());

foreach ($driverIDs as $id) {
    $obj  = new StdClass;
    $name = $pkm->where('izdao_to', $id)->first()->izdaoFirstName;
    $lastname = $pkm->where('izdao_to', $id)->first()->izdaoLastName;
    $cnt = $pkm->where('izdao_to', $id)->count();
    $total = $pkm->where('izdao_to', $id)->sum('vrednost');
    $admin = $pkm->where('izdao_to', $id)->first()->izdao_by;
    $izdato = $pkm->where('izdao_to', $id)->first()->izdao_at;
  
    $obj->name = $name;
    $obj->lastname = $lastname;
    $obj->cnt = $cnt;
    $obj->total = $total;
    $obj->admin = $admin;
    $obj->izdato = $izdato;
    dump($obj);
}
```

this is my view

```
@foreach ($obj as $items)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$loop->iteration}}</td>
        <td>{{$obj->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$obj->lastname}}</td>
        <td>{{$obj->cnt }}</td>
        <td>{{$obj->total}}</td>
        <td>{{\App\User::find($obj->admin)->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$obj->izdato }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

i think i need one more foreach loop in controller where is $obj->name = $name

Comment: In your controller, what variable does you return?

Comment: i tried to return all, but its the same, for now i return obj

Comment: Could you please share the code which return obj in your controller?

Comment: do you think on this ?              `        return view('superadmin/izvestaji/izvestajiVozaca', compact('pkm','obj'));
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just create an array which contains all objects and return this array in your controller.

```
$pkm = DB::table('magacin_pkms')->select(
    'magacin_pkms.status',
    'magacin_pkms.izdao_to',
    'users.name as izdaoFirstName',
    'users.lastname as izdaoLastName',
    'magacin_pkms.vrednost',
    'magacin_pkms.izdao_by',
    'magacin_pkms.izdao_at'
)
    ->join('users', 'id_user', 'izdao_to')
    ->where('magacin_pkms.status', 2)
    ->orderBy('izdao_to')
    ->get();

$driverIDs = array_unique($pkm->pluck('izdao_to')->toArray());

//you initialize an array 
$arrObj = [];
foreach ($driverIDs as $id) {
    $obj  = new StdClass;
    $name = $pkm->where('izdao_to', $id)->first()->izdaoFirstName;
    $lastname = $pkm->where('izdao_to', $id)->first()->izdaoLastName;
    $cnt = $pkm->where('izdao_to', $id)->count();
    $total = $pkm->where('izdao_to', $id)->sum('vrednost');
    $admin = $pkm->where('izdao_to', $id)->first()->izdao_by;
    $izdato = $pkm->where('izdao_to', $id)->first()->izdao_at;
  
    $obj->name = $name;
    $obj->lastname = $lastname;
    $obj->cnt = $cnt;
    $obj->total = $total;
    $obj->admin = $admin;
    $obj->izdato = $izdato;
    dump($obj);
    //you add this object into array
    $arrObj[] = $obj;
}

return view('superadmin/izvestaji/izvestajiVozaca', compact('arrObj'));
```

In your view

```
@foreach ($arrObj as $obj)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$loop->iteration}}</td>
        <td>{{$obj->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$obj->lastname}}</td>
        <td>{{$obj->cnt }}</td>
        <td>{{$obj->total}}</td>
        <td>{{\App\User::find($obj->admin)->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$obj->izdato }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a dd in the view, like:

- `{{ dd($obj) }}`
- `{{ dd($items) }}` (inside foreach)

Comment: i'm getting results the same like i'm getting with dump

Comment: dd stands for dump and die, and dd will stop script execution, you'd never get more output than just the first one in the loop https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-dd

Comment: i know that, when i remove dump, and using dd i'm getting only one record, how to get all records, i think i need one more foreach in controller but i'm not so sure, i'm not so good in oop php